What are the Easement offsets for poles and power lines?
How close can I build my garage to a power pole? And how close can my new house be to the power line? Thanks
https://share.icloud.com/photos/04dPj3exUySdUhzZoP9oNDeEQ

I’m voting to close this question because local code questions are off topic per the [help].

This is something that is very localized. You need to contact your local building authority.
I have had garages almost touching a power pole and lived in other areas where nothing can be built within 10 feet.
If you are constructing a home or large garage you usually need a survey. Surveyors will mark the easements on your printed survey if you are sure to tell them you want them noted.
Often a survey is needed to get a building permit. Again, however it depends on your location. We cannot give you a definitive answer here.

My property is in Fieldale Virginia and the power company is Appalachian Electric Power.

The easment offsets will vary by zoning authorities. In South Florida, rear lot easememts are 6' on each side of the property line for a total easment of 12'.  Front lot easements are 10' from the property/right-of-way line.  The NEC has vertical and horazontal clearances buildings must be from powerlines but they depend on voltages and types of cables. Many power companies also have their own rules. Aerial encroachments of powerlines are another can of worms I won't open.
